# Unmarshalling in Go returns a blank output

Tags: go, xml-parsing, unmarshalling

I get a blank output for the print statements below. Only for the second print statement I get the xml structure. Is the issue with my struct? I have generated the structs using Chidley (https://github.com/gnewton/chidley) .

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

type Query struct {
    rpc Rpc_reply `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 rpc-reply,omitempty" json:"rpc-reply,omitempty"`
}

type Addr_tag_list struct {
    Addr_tag Addr_tag `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 addr,omitempty" json:"addr,omitempty"`
    Pref_tag Pref_tag `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 pref,omitempty" json:"pref,omitempty"`
    Tag Tag `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 tag,omitempty" json:"tag,omitempty"`
    Type_tag Type_tag `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 type,omitempty" json:"type,omitempty"`
    VpcPeer_tag VpcPeer_tag `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 vpcPeer,omitempty" json:"vpcPeer,omitempty"`
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 Addr-list,omitempty" json:"Addr-list,omitempty"`
}

type Dom_list struct {
    If_items If_items `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 if-items,omitempty" json:"if-items,omitempty"`
    Name_tag Name_tag `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 name,omitempty" json:"name,omitempty"`
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 Dom-list,omitempty" json:"Dom-list,omitempty"`
}

type If_list struct {
    Addr_items_tag Addr_items_tag `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 addr-items,omitempty" json:"addr-items,omitempty"`
    Id_tag Id_tag `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 id,omitempty" json:"id,omitempty"`
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 If-list,omitempty" json:"If-list,omitempty"`
}

type Systemtag struct {
    Ipv4_items Ipv4_items `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 ipv4-items,omitempty" json:"ipv4-items,omitempty"`
    Test_name Test_name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 test-name,omitempty" json:"test-name,omitempty"`
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 System,omitempty" json:"System,omitempty"`
}

type Addr_tag struct {
    Text string `xml:",chardata" json:",omitempty"`
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 addr,omitempty" json:"addr,omitempty"`
}

type Addr_items_tag struct {
    Addr_tag_list Addr_tag_list `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 Addr-list,omitempty" json:"Addr-list,omitempty"`
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 addr-items,omitempty" json:"addr-items,omitempty"`
}

type Data_tag struct {
    Systemtag Systemtag `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 System,omitempty" json:"System,omitempty"`
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 data,omitempty" json:"data,omitempty"`
}

type Dom_items struct {
    Dom_list []Dom_list `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 Dom-list,omitempty" json:"Dom-list,omitempty"`
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 dom-items,omitempty" json:"dom-items,omitempty"`
}

type Id_tag struct {
    Text string `xml:",chardata" json:",omitempty"`
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 id,omitempty" json:"id,omitempty"`
}

type If_items struct {
    If_list []If_list `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 If-list,omitempty" json:"If-list,omitempty"`
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 if-items,omitempty" json:"if-items,omitempty"`
}

type Inst_items struct {
    Dom_items Dom_items `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 dom-items,omitempty" json:"dom-items,omitempty"`
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 inst-items,omitempty" json:"inst-items,omitempty"`
}

type Ipv4_items struct {
    Inst_items Inst_items `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 inst-items,omitempty" json:"inst-items,omitempty"`
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 ipv4-items,omitempty" json:"ipv4-items,omitempty"`
}

type Name_tag struct {
    Text string `xml:",chardata" json:",omitempty"`
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 name,omitempty" json:"name,omitempty"`
}

type Pref_tag struct {
    Text bool `xml:",chardata" json:",omitempty"`
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 pref,omitempty" json:"pref,omitempty"`
}

type Rpc_reply struct {
    Attr_message_id string `xml:" message-id,attr"  json:",omitempty"`
    Attr_xmlns string `xml:" xmlns,attr"  json:",omitempty"`
    Data_tag Data_tag `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 data,omitempty" json:"data,omitempty"`
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 rpc-reply,omitempty" json:"rpc-reply,omitempty"`
}

type Tag struct {
    Text bool `xml:",chardata" json:",omitempty"`
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 tag,omitempty" json:"tag,omitempty"`
}

type Type_tag struct {
    Text string `xml:",chardata" json:",omitempty"`
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 type,omitempty" json:"type,omitempty"`
}

type VpcPeer_tag struct {
    Text string `xml:",chardata" json:",omitempty"`
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 vpcPeer,omitempty" json:"vpcPeer,omitempty"`
}

type Test_name struct {
    Text string `xml:",chardata" json:",omitempty"`
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0 test-name,omitempty" json:"test-name,omitempty"`
}


func main() {
    xmlFile, err := os.Open("interface.xml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error opening file:", err)
        return
    }
    defer xmlFile.Close()

    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)

    var q Query
    err2 := xml.Unmarshal(b, &q)
    if err2 != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err2)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(q)
    //fmt.Printf("%#v",q)
     fmt.Printf("%s",q.rpc.Attr_message_id);

}
```

A sample of the interface.xml file is :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rpc-reply xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="1">
  <data>
    <System>
     <test-name>##WORK##</test-name>
      <ipv4-items>
        <inst-items>
          <dom-items>
            <Dom-list>
              <name>default</name>
              <if-items>
                <If-list>
                  <id>eth5/8</id>
                  <addr-items>
                    <Addr-list>
                      <addr>1.1.1.1</addr>
                      <pref>1</pref>
                      <tag>0</tag>
                      <type>primary</type>
                      <vpcPeer>0.0.0.0</vpcPeer>
                    </Addr-list>
                  </addr-items>
                </If-list>
                </if-items>
              </Dom-list>
               <Dom-list>
              <name>management</name>
              <if-items>
                <If-list>
                  <id>eth5/8</id>
                  <addr-items>
                    <Addr-list>
                      <addr>11.11.11.11</addr>
                      <pref>1</pref>
                      <tag>0</tag>
                      <type>primary</type>
                      <vpcPeer>0.0.0.0</vpcPeer>
                    </Addr-list>
                  </addr-items>
                </If-list>
                </if-items>
              </Dom-list>
              </dom-items>
        </inst-items>
      </ipv4-items>
    </System>
  </data>
</rpc-reply>
```

You may load the xml data http://countwordsfree.com/xmlviewer to get a better view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is struct you're passing doesn't have element in the XML hierarchy (`XMLName  xml.Name` mapping).

Change these two lines to-

```
var rpc Rpc_reply
err2 := xml.Unmarshal(b, &rpc)
```